# Add Objects from one Array to Another at a Specific Position

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two Mutable Arrays, firstArray and secondArray. Both are populated with objects. I want to add the objects from secondArray to firstArray at a specific point (not at the end and not at the beginning) in the firstArray. Is there a way to do this? Currently I'm only using this line of code:

```
[self.firstArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```

What I want is FOO CODE: self.firstArray addObjectFromArray AT SPECIFIC POINT X: secondArray,specificpointX)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering my own question, this works:

```
 int z;
 z = (int)self.specificPosition;

 // Start adding at index position z and secondArray has count items

 NSRange range = NSMakeRange(z, [secondArray count]);     
 NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
 [self.firstArray insertObjects:secondArray atIndexes:indexSet];
```

Comment: +1 Great! I'm glad you managed to make it work! Apologies again for the error in my answer that may have mislead...

Comment: It gave me the following error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:atIndexes:]: count of array (392) differs from count of index set (200)'

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You just need to use the `insertObject:AtIndex:` function.

I've listed a simple example below where I create an array of size 10 and add an object at index 5.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[myArray insertObject:@"Hello World" AtIndex:5];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There is also 'insertObjects:atIndexes:' for adding an array of objects to another array at given indices.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, that works for inserting a single object into an array, but I want to insert all objects in a second array. I suppose I could do a count and loop the insertObject code, but I see there's also insertObjects method (with an 's') but it refers to: atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes. I have no idea what an NSIndexSet is and how to use that.

Comment: Yes - you could do a loop. Using an Index Set would be better though. An Index Set is just an array of indices (or positions) describing where you would like each element of the array you're adding to be inserted into. There's a really nice example in the insertObjects:atIndixes Apple documentation. If you're still having trouble, I'll edit my post and include an example! Good luck! N

Comment: @Nick Your example is broken: `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]` does not create an array of 10 elements. It creates an **empty** array with room for at least 10 elements. The second line of your example would crash (mind the lowercase `atIndex:`, b.t.w.).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:**

```
let insetIndex = 3  // your any insert index
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let array2 = ["10", "11"]
array1.insert(contentsOf: array2, at: insetIndex)
```

**OC:**

```
int loc = 3;  // your any insert index
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10", @"11", nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(loc, array2.count);  // NOTE: NSMakeRange(NSUInteger loc, NSUInteger len)  len must be your array2.cout, or will crash with differs from count of index set

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[array1 insertObjects:array2 atIndexes:indexSet];
```

output: ["1", "2", "3", "10", "11", "4", "5"]